# function in javascript not working when called

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that works by removing the first and the last line of it.

Please take a look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subTZ/59/)

for people who wants to see it in here, here is my html:

```
<input id="search" onclick="search()" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

my javascript :

```
    function search() {
var search = document.getElementById('search');

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if (search.value.length == 6)
        search.value = 'Searchi';
    else if (search.value.length == 7)
        search.value = 'Searchin';
    else if (search.value.length == 8)
    search.value = 'Searching';
    else {
        search.value= 'Search';
            }
    //clearInterval( int ); // at some point, clear the setInterval
}, 500);

}
```

I want the function to work only when I click the button.

Comment: See .. it works :http://jsfiddle.net/subTZ/61/

Comment: Select "no wrap (head)" in jsFiddle, solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've selected `jQuery` in jsfiddle.net which by default causes the site to wrap your whole code in a `document.ready` handler.

The result is that your `search` function becomes a local function within that wrapper, and not a global variable as required by a DOM0 `onclick` handler.

Set the jsfiddle options to "no wrap (body)" and "No-Library (pure js)" to turn off that functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the tip and it worked in the JSFiddle website. but I cannot manage it to work in a normal HTML document. Is there certain objects that I need to fix inside the HTML document?

Comment: @shnisaka I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code, although putting JS event handlers inside an `onclick` attribute is considered very old fashioned these days.